# Parsing .rodata (ELF)

Tags: ida, elf, static-analysis

IDA pro is able to display the data contained in the *read only data* section of ELF files, but the section is defined as type SHT_PROGBITS.

To my knowledge, we cannot parse sections of this type to resolve information such as constant data/variable names.

So my question is how do tools such as IDA actually get the information in .rodata or other SHT_PROGBITS sections such as .PLT.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to [ELF-format](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf) `SHT_PROGBITS` meens only that

> The section holds information defined by the program, whose format and meaning are determined solely by the program.

But ELF-section's type is not the only (and not main) attribute for parsing data from file. There are also section's **name** and **attributes**.

Sections like `.text` and `.data` also have `SHT_PROGBITS`-type, but their names are **special**.

Generally (and very simply) the process of ELF-parsing is so:

1. Read File header
2. Read Section Headers table
3. Read Symbol table
4. Make Relocations

More info you can take from IDA's ELF-loader (`IDA_Dir\loaders\elf.ldw` (or dll)) or from a tools like **readelf**.

Comment: could you elaborate on names being special? Thanks

Comment: Special names are `.bss`, `.comment`, `.data` `.debug`, `.dynamic`, `.dynstr`, `.dynsym`, `.fini`, `.got`, `.hash`, `.init`, `.interp`, `.line`, `.note`, `.plt`, `.rel<name>`, `.rodata`, `.shstrtab`, `.strtab`, `.symtab`, `.text`